# Open images? Python

Tags: python, image, python-2.7

Im creating a text based labryinth game, but I figured it needed some pictures to illustrate whats going on. For some reason it just dies when I try to go to a2(Where the picture should pop up). I am a beginner so dont judge my code so much ^^

```
import Image
a1 = ("a1 Go to the start of the Labyrinth", "You're at the start of the labyrinth") #Start
a2 = ("a2 Go Left", "You've chosen to go left, unfortunatly it leads to nothing.") #Fail route
a3 = ("a3 Go Right", "You've chosen to go right.") #Right route
a4 = ("a4 Go Left", "You've chosen to go left") #Fail route
a5 = ("a5 Go Right", "You've chosen to go right") #Right route
a6 = ("a6 Go Right", "You've chosen to go right") #Fail route; end
a7 = ("a7 Go Left", "You've chosen to go left") #Fail route
a8 = ("a8 Go Left", "You've chosen to go left") #Fail route; end
a9 = ("a9 Go Right", "You've chosen to go right") #Fail route; end
a10 = ("a10 Go Forwards", "You've chosen to go forwards") #Right route
a11 = ("a11 Go left", "You've chosen to go left; Congratulations, you won! You may restart") #Right route; end; victory
fail = ("fail End game", "You lost!") #End game
b1 = ("b1 Go Left", "You've chosen to go left")
b2 = ("b2 Go Right", "You've chosen to go right")
b3 = ("b3 Go Left", "You've chosen to go left")

transitions = {
    a1: (a2, a3),
    a2: (fail, a1),
    a3: (b1,),
    b1: (a4, a5,),
    a4: (b2,),
    b2: (a7, a6,),
    a5: (b3,),
    b3: (a9, a10,),
    a6: (fail, a1),
    a7: (a8,),
    a8: (fail, a1),
    a9: (fail, a1),
    a10: (a11,),
    a11: (a1,)
}

location = a1

while True:
    print location[1]
    print ("Here you can: ")

    for (i, t) in enumerate(transitions[location]):
        print i + 1, t[0]

    choice = int(raw_input("Choose one "))
    location = transitions[location][choice - 1]

    if location == a2:
        Image.open(picture.jpg)
        Img.show
```

Answer (score 52):

Instead of

```
Image.open(picture.jpg)
Img.show
```

You should have

```
from PIL import Image

#...

img = Image.open('picture.jpg')
img.show()
```

You should probably also think about an other system to show your messages, because this way it will be a lot of manual work. Look into string substitution (using `%s` or `.format()`).

Comment: Now it says
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
How do I define it?

Comment: Image should be defined when you imported Image at the top

Comment: @CasperOlsson: I added the correct import to my code, that should work.

Comment: @CasperOlsson This is correct, it should be marked as such.

Comment: Can I convert the image into grayscale by sending any argument?

Answer (score 6):

Open any file

```
import os
os.startfile(<filepath>)
```

Comment: it gives me: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'startfile'

Answer (score 1):

This is how to open any file:

```
from os import path

filepath = '...' # your path
file = open(filepath, 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if location == a2:
    img = Image.open("picture.jpg")
    Img.show
```

Make sure the name of the image is in parantheses 
this should work