# Navigation panel is not shown on big figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pickle

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
f = plt.figure(figsize=(32, 24))
#f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show(block=False)
```

If I initialize figure with `figsize=(8, 6)` it shows navigation bar normally

[image]

But if I initialize it with `figsize=(32, 24)` it doesn't show navigation bar, even if I resize figure window to small size

[image]

Why and how to fix? Is it possible to force navigation bar to appear programmatically?

---

If I do

```
f.canvas.toolbar.setVisible(True)
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'NavigationToolbar2TkAgg' object has no attribute 'setVisible'
```

and if I do

```
f.canvas.toolbar.pack_forget()
```

I have no errors but also have no navigation bar.

How to restore navigation bar on Tk or portable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212204/how-can-i-display-a-matplotlib-interactive-window-without-any-of-the-controls-vi

Comment: @caverac it's opposite but thanks